# Why will updateOne not work on my schema?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

This is my current code:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const schema = require("../schemas/ecos");
module.exports = async(req, res) => {
  const db = await schema.findOne({
      RobloxID: req.query.roblox_id
  });
  if(db.IsPendingVerification === "true") {
    res.send({
      success: true
    })
    db.updateOne({
      IsNowVerified: "true"
    })
  }
}
```

at the moment it will not update the DB so IsNowVerified is true. Why might this be? I do not get any errors.

My Ecos file:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  Guild: { type: String, default: "" },
  VerifyChannelID: { type: String, default: "" },
  VerifyRoleID: { type: String, default: "" },
  Prefix: { type: String, default: "v-" },
  GuildToken: { type: String, default: "" },
  HasGeneratedToken: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  VerificationLevel1: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  VerificationLevel2: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  VerificationLevel3: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  VerifcationRBLX: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  VerificationRBLXGameLink: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  VerifyMessageWelcomeID: { type: String, default: "" },
  GuildName: { type: String, default: "" },
  GuildInvite: { type: String, default: "" },
  UserID: { type: String, default: "" },
  RobloxID: { type: String, default: "" },
  IsPendingVerification: { type: String, default: "" },
  IsNowVerified: { type: String, default: "" }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Eco", productSchema, "ecos");
```

That is the module exports for the ecos of the mongodb database.

Comment: You need to provide two parameters to the `updateOne` method, filter and update command. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-updateOne

Comment: What would be my 2nd parameter then?

Comment: Can you show the contents of your `schemas/ecos` file?

Comment: ok will do now!

Comment: done you can now overview it

Comment: @caffeinated.tech I updated it

Comment: @caffeinated.tech what you put did not work

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the error message?

Comment: it just does not update @caffeinated.tech

Comment: I can't help you there, you will need to do some debugging. Add log statements to see what your code is doing and how far it is getting, eg.`console.log("isPendingVerification", document.isPendingVerification)`. And look into your DB using either the mongo cli, or use a GUI like NoSQLBooster to look at the documents in DB to see if they have the fields set to the values you expect them to be

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a little confusing, so I've changed some names, but left the functionality the same:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Eco = require("../schemas/ecos");

module.exports = async(req, res) => {
  const document = await Eco.findOne({
      RobloxID: req.query.roblox_id
  });
  if(document.IsPendingVerification === "true") {
    document.IsNowVerified = "true"
    await document.save()
    res.send({
      success: true
    })
  }
```

Now I'll go through the changes:

```
const Eco = require("../schemas/ecos");
```

What you are exporting isn't a schema, but the [model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html). The model is the class defining what entries in your database `ecos` collection look like. You likely have multiple models, so best to name them properly.

```
  const document = await Eco.findOne({
      RobloxID: req.query.roblox_id
  });
```

What the `findOne` query returns is an instance of the Model, representing the [document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html) found in the collection. This has all the info in the database document, as well as lots of useful methods to help you modify it.

```
    document.IsNowVerified = "true"
    await document.save()
```

You can directly modify this document, and then [save](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-save) it to the database. This updates the document in database with any changes you made to it.

The [updateOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-updateOne) is used directly on the model, for example:

```
    await Eco.updateOne({
      RobloxID: req.query.roblox_id
    }, {
      IsNowVerified = "true"
    })
```

This finds the document by the `RobloxId`, then updates the fields passed in the second object, in this case `IsNowVerified`
This is useful as it's a single DB query, so it's quick. But as you want to first check another field, it's better to first find the document and then update it.

---

Another thing, is to change `"true"` to `true`. this will use `Boolean` in DB rather than `string`, which takes up much less space, and is the standard practice, which will lead to less errors. But as you're already using the `"true"` version, changing it will probably cause lots of errors unless you change it everywhere.